# Blazor ServerSide Server Prerender In Safari browser only Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have Blazor ServerSide application work in ServerPrerendered mode.

Only in safari browser (mac IOS) I get Error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor:{"sequence":1,"type":"server","prerenderId":"0fa134f8691f4f728428ba1ec1261f6a","descriptor":"CfDJ8Eu5BzyCn8VNtRM6v/\u002B7yL0vFX5o8vOPy3\u002BtbkCB6t...

And this error only in ServerPrerendered mode, Server mode works Ok.

I have no idea what is it and how to debug it.

So I'm remove  all image as base64  as  possible reason, but it not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in loosing tag body in _Host, and  add it in , mainlayout stupid mistake with strange result.